# Incorrect syntax near 'varchar'. Incorrect syntax near 'Type'

Tags: sql, winforms, ado.net

Can Anybody tell me Where is the error, I am getting Error at cmd.ExecuteNonquery() i.e Incorrect syntax near 'varchar'. Incorrect syntax near 'Type'.

```
 string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RelayTestMachine.Properties.Settings.RelayTestConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TestValue (Relay Type,Applied Voltage) VALUES(@Relay Type,@Applied Voltage)",con);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Relay Type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbRelayType.Text;

                if (rbtn100.Checked == true)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Applied Voltage", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rbtn100.Text;
                }
                if (rbtn75.Checked == true)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Applied Voltage", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rbtn75.Text;
                }
                con.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

Comment: Column names cannot contain spaces unless you `""` or `[]` quote them. Variable names cannot contain spaces.

Comment: dont give spaces between @relay type

Comment: spaces are not allowed in the variable names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove white spaces from variable name and add `[]` to column names.

> White Spaces are not allowed in variable name and if column names
>   consist of spaces in between then they must be enclosed with `[]` or
>   `""`

```
INSERT INTO TestValue ([Relay Type],[Applied Voltage]) VALUES(@RelayType,@AppliedVoltage)"
```

the whole goes like this

```
string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RelayTestMachine.Properties.Settings.RelayTestConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TestValue ([Relay Type],[Applied Voltage]) VALUES(@RelayType,@AppliedVoltage)",con);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RelayType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbRelayType.Text;

                if (rbtn100.Checked == true)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@AppliedVoltage", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rbtn100.Text;
                }
                if (rbtn75.Checked == true)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@AppliedVoltage", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rbtn75.Text;
                }
                con.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this insert statement

```
INSERT INTO TestValue ([Relay Type],[Applied Voltage]) VALUES(@RelayType,@AppliedVoltage)
```

i.e, you need to remove the spaces from variable names and put the column names inside the []